# Why POST's requests don't parse?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

learn express and faced with problem. After i create module body-parser begin don't work. All requests are complited, but data don't parsing.

```
let express        = require('express');
let bp             = require('body-parser');
let dishRouter     = require('./dishRouter');
let app            = express();
let hostname       = 'localhost';
let port           = 8080;

dishRouter.use(bp.json()); //don't work

app.use('/dishes', dishRouter);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen(port, hostname, function(){
    console.log(__dirname);
    console.log(`Server has running at http://${hostname}:${port}`);
});
```

//My dishRouter module

```
let express = require('express');
let router  = express.Router();

router.route('/')
.all(function(req, res, next){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/plain'});
    next();
})
.get(function(req, res, next){
    res.end('We will dish for you');
})
.post(function(req, res, next){
    res.end('Will add the dish:' + req.body.name + ' with details: ' + req.body.description);
})
.delete(function(req, res, next){
    res.end('Deleting all dishes');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Are you sure you're sending your requests with `Content-Type: application/json`? How are you performing the requests?

Comment: I use postman and when my code in route module was in one file with main code, all warks perfectly. Now all requests are work, but dont work body-parser. May be issue in exports module?

Comment: I decide this problem. Issue in my string dishRouter.use. As i think object, which returned express.Pouter() don't  have method use. Need write: app.use(bp.json). Figured out, this is my error. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

As this Example you miss send after rest:

```
app.route('/book')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    res.send('Get a random book');
  })
  .post(function(req, res) {
    res.send('Add a book');
  })
  .put(function(req, res) {
    res.send('Update the book');
  });
```

Comment: `.send()` isn't necessary and this code is equivalent to the code in the question (it sends a default status code of 200, writes the passed content to the response, and then ends the response).